# JDBCRealm doesn't work but there is no error message

Tags: java, mysql, jdbcrealm

I hope that some one can help me. I try to configure the authentification via a JDBCRealm. It is the first time do this.

Here are my Tables:

```
*Table userprincipal*
email : varchar
password : varchar

*Table role*
email : varchar
role : varchar
```

I use a Tomcat 7 Server. So i changed the server.xml from

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm"> 
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
</Realm>
```

to (with correct login data)

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
        driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myData"
        connectionName="user" 
        connectionPassword="pwd" 
        userTable="userprincipal"
        userNameCol="EMAIL" 
        userCredCol="password" 
        userRoleTable="userprincipal_role"
        roleNameCol="role" />
```

I added to the web.xml following lines

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Default</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/customer/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/services/material/loadAllByQuery</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/services/SalesOrder/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

When I start the Application and I call a URL which only admins and users can access I get the login popup from the browser. But if I logged in with correct user data the popup comes again. Other pages without a login working fine.

There are no exceptions, no warnings, no other erros displayed in the console.

How can I figured out whats the problem?

SDK is Java 1.7
Tomcat version is 7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is the Tomcat installation. I installed it via Eclipse. Now I installed it manually und deployed the war file of my project. It works.